# Netflix and apple tv resolution

Tags: bandwidth, netflix

Is it possible to force netflix to play standard definition when using apple tv? Or do the in browser netflix settings apply to apple tv streaming of netflix also.

By settings I mean the play back settings in user account settings for netflix

Comment: What exactly is your question.  There isn't a version of Apple TV that supports 4K video.  Which means even if Netflix does and your bandwidth would support it, your limited by the hardware,in the Apple TV.

Comment: Well apple tv seems to just stream netflix in HD which takes up 99% of bandwidth, is there anyway to force it stream in SD? (by hd i mean 1080p/720p)